# what is the number +0x71/0x420 meaning in call trace?

Tags: kernel

When seeing a call trace,

```
WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at arch/x86/kernel/cpu/mce/core.c:1490 mcheck_cpu_init+0x71/0x420
```

1490 is the source code line number.

what about the `+0x71/0x420` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number is [the offset inside the function](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/bug-hunting.html), the second is [the size of the function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.15.8/source/kernel/kallsyms.c#L441).

The warning was produced as a result of something which happened when the instruction pointer was 0x71 bytes after the start of `mcheck_cpu_init` (this gives the line in the source code), and `mcheck_cpu_init` is a 0x420-byte-long function.